# Effectively Pooling Instances of ByteBuffer

Tags: java, pool, apache-commons-pool

I am writing a messaging facade that takes in arbitrary POJOs and sends them across the wire in JSON format, with the following workflow:

1. User invokes `MessagingFacade.sendMessage(Object)`
2. Borrow a ByteBuffer from a pool, we will serailize the message into this buffer
3. Convert POJO into JSON by invoking `JsonSerializer.serialize(Object, ByteBuffer)`
4. Send the encoded message over the wire `Transport.send(ByteBuffer)`, keep a reference to a promise that will be notified when the message has been sent
5. Attach a callback to the promise to return the ByteBuffer to the pool once it has been written down the wire
6. Return from `MessagingFacade.sendMessage(Object)` invocation

This is a relatively trivial use-case for pooling ByteBuffers, given we can invoke `clear()` to reset the state when the object is returned to the pool.

---

Rather than writing my own object pool, I have attempted to utilize those already offered in Apache `commons-pool`. However, there seems to be a rather large caveat with `GenericObjectPool` and `SoftReferenceObjectPool`...

When borrowing / returning objects, these two pools are using `hashCode()` and / or `equals()` to identify the associated `PooledObject<ByteBuffer>`. This has a very real implications on `ByteBuffer`, given the `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations involve evaluating the contents of the underlying `byte` array:

1. Cleaning of Object - When the `ByteBuffer` is returned to the pool, it has its state "cleaned". This simply involves calling `ByteBuffer.clear()`. This does not zero-out all the bytes in the array, which means that `equals()` and `hashCode()` give different results when returning the `ByteBuffer`, versus when it was borrowed.
2. Speed of Evaluation - Given I'm pooling instances of `ByteBuffer` with a capacity of my maximum message size (1MB), evaluating both `hashCode()` and `equals()` has to linearly traverse this very large array

---

The Apache commons-pool implementations do not seem suitable for any use-case where either (a) the class has expensive `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations or (b) `hashCode()` does not yield stable results after being cleaned.

The only viable option to make `GenericObjectPool` or `SoftReferenceObjectPool` work for this use case seems to be to wrap the `ByteBuffer` in another class which uses identity equality / hash-code logic.

This is working, but feels a little cumbersome given how vanilla this use-case is. Are there better alternatives to this approach?

---

One final note; due to the instability of `equals()` and `hashCode()` one will actually get exceptions from the `GenericObjectPool`, because the pool believes you are attempting to return an object that was never borrrowed from the pool:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Returned object not currently part of this pool
 at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.returnObject(GenericObjectPool.java:537)
 ...
```

Comment: Sounds like you'd need an implementation that uses `IdentityHashMap` instead of a regular `HashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

The limitation you are referring to was identified in the JIRA issues POOL-283 and POOL-284, which were resolved in version 2.4.1 of Commons Pool.  Try upgrading to version 2.4.1.